# Find centroid of the coordinates stored in GeoJson Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I have recently started working on GeoJson in Mongodb.
I have collection named `Restaurants` which stores the coordinates of the restaurants in GeoJson POINT object.
Is there a mongodb way of finding the centroid of the collection?

Schema of the Restaurants is as given below:

```
"use strict";
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const restaurantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  geoCoordinates: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["Point"],
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
    },
  },
  createdTimestamp: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  lastUpdatedTimestamp: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

const Restaurants = mongoose.model("Restaurants", restaurantSchema, "Restaurants");

module.exports = {
  Restaurants,
};
```

Thank you,
KK

Comment: Can you add some sample documents from the restaurant's collection, to the question?

Comment: I have updated the question with the schema of Restaurant collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `$group` and calculate the `$avg`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {
      _id: 0,
      lon: {$push: {$arrayElemAt: ["$location.coordinates", 0]}},
      lat: {$push: {$arrayElemAt: ["$location.coordinates", 1]}}
  }},
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      centroid: [{$avg: "$lon"}, {$avg: "$lat"}]
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c1FgieS_ZRG)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One question, does the average of lat lng gives the centroid? Do we need to convert that to UTM first?

Comment: As far as I know the centroid is the average of all points. If you want to convert it to UTM (which was not mentioned in the question), you can convert the result.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The answer helped me to solve the issue I was facing. And the mongodb playground is a bonus.